# Equivalence relation for homogeneous coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, relations, coordinate-systems, equivalence-relations

My geometry textbook states that the vectors $(a, b, c)^T$ and $k(a, b, c)^T$ represent the same line for any non-zero $k$; in other words, two such vectors related by an overall scaling are considered equivalent. It then goes on to state that an equivalence class of vectors under this equivalence relationship is known as a *homogeneous* vector.

The Wikipedia page for homogeneous coordinates [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates#Alternative_definition) that for non-zero elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$, $(x_1, y_1, z_1) \sim (x_2, y_2, z_3)$ is defined to mean there is a non-zero $\lambda$ so that $(x_1, y_1, z_1) =  (\lambda x_2, \lambda y_2, \lambda z_2)$. Then $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

1. I'm confused as to how this could be an equivalence relationship, since equivalence relations are *binary* relations, whereas this is a *triple* relation?
2. If this is an equivalence relation, then what is the relation in set theoretic notation? I have the following: If $X = \{(a, b, c)^T \mid a, b, c \in \mathbb{R} \}$, then the relation on $X$ is $R = \{ (x, y, z)^T \mid (x, y, z)^T = k(a, b, c)^T \ \text{for some $k \in (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}) $} \}$. Is this correct? If not, then what's wrong with it?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: There are TWO triples being related, so it is binary.

Comment: @Randall Wikipedia gives the following definition of binary relation: In mathematics, a binary relation over two sets $A$ and $B$ is a set of ordered pairs $(a, b)$ consisting of elements $a$ of $A$ and elements $b$ of $B$; in short, it is a subset of the Cartesian product $A \times B$. Can you please elaborate on how what you're saying is in agreement with said definition?

Comment: $A$ is the set of all triples and so is $B$.  The special subset of the product is formed by those pairs of triples that relate.

Comment: The given relation is a subset of $(\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\times\Bbb R)\times (\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\times\Bbb R)$.

Comment: @Berci Hmm, I see. So my $X$ is incorrect? And so is my relation $R$?

Comment: Someone else will come along and do a better job than me.

Comment: @Randall Thanks for the input! :)

Comment: Yes, it is correct, as $X=\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Berci But you said that the given relation is a subset of $(\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\times\Bbb R)\times (\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\times\Bbb R)$? So shouldn't it be $X = (\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\times\Bbb R)\times (\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\times\Bbb R)$? And this would also change $R$?

Comment: We say $R$ is a relation over set $X$, when $R\subseteq X\times X$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Ahh, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification. So should $R$ actually be $R = \{ ((x, y, z), (a, b, c))^T \mid (x, y, z)^T = k(a, b, c)^T \ \text{for some $k \in (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}) $} \}$ (I'm confused about where to put the first transpose now, haha)?

Comment: $R=\{\langle\langle a,b,c\rangle^\top,k\langle a,b,c\rangle^\top\rangle\mid \langle a,b,c\rangle\in \Bbb R^3, k\in(\Bbb R\smallsetminus\{0\})\}$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Ok, I think I understand it now. Thank you.

Comment: @GrahamKemp After further thought, I think the correct relation is $R = \{ ((a, b, c)^T, (x, y, z)^T) \mid (a, b, c)^T = k(x, y, z)^T, (x, y, z)^T \in X, k \in (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}) \}$. See my proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220494/proof-equivalence-relation-for-homogeneous-coordinates

Comment: @ThePointer They are equivalent. Every element in the relation is a pair of three-dimentional vectors which are (non-zero) scalar multiples.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Ok. I was just having trouble formulating a proof with the former version, so I rewrote it as the latter. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Sorry.  Allow me to rephrase: Yes, I agree your relation is also a correct as I find them to be equivalent.  So if you can work with that, you have a representation of the equivalence relation.