# Proof: Equivalence relation for homogeneous coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, proof-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

My geometry textbook states that the vectors $(a, b, c)^T$ and $k(a, b, c)^T$ represent the same line for any non-zero $k$; in other words, two such vectors related by an overall scaling are considered equivalent. It then goes on to state that an equivalence class of vectors under this equivalence relationship is known as a *homogeneous* vector.

I want to prove that this relation is indeed an equivalence relation.

So let $X = \{(a, b, c)^T \mid a, b, c \in \mathbb{R} \}$, and define the relation $R = \{ ((a, b, c)^T, (x, y, z)^T) \mid (a, b, c)^T = k(x, y, z)^T, (x, y, z)^T \in X, k \in (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}) \}$ over $X$ ($R \subseteq X \times X$) . I will now prove that $R$ is **reflexive**, **symmetric**, and **transitive**.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review my work for correctness.

**Reflexivity:**

Let $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)^T \in X$.

$\therefore (x_1, x_2, x_3)^T = k(x_1, x_2, x_3)^T$ when $k = 1$

Since $k = 1 \in \mathbb{R}$, $(x_1, x_2, x_3)^T \in X$, and $(x_1, x_2, x_3)^T = k(x_1, x_2, x_3)^T$, we can conclude that $((x_1, x_2, x_3)^T, (x_1, x_2, x_3)^T) \in R$ and $x \sim x$.

$Q.E.D.$

**Symmetry:**

Let $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)^T \in X$ and $y = (y_1, y_2, y_3)^T \in X$.

1. (Proof that $(x \sim y) \Rightarrow (y \sim x)$.)

Assume that $(x \sim y)$.

$\therefore (x_1, x_2, x_3)^T = k(y_1, y_2, y_3)^T$, where $k \in (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \})$

(By the definition of $R$.)

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{k} (x_1, x_2, x_3)^T = (y_1, y_2, y_3)^T$

$\Rightarrow K (x_1, x_2, x_3)^T = (y_1, y_2, y_3)^T$, where $\dfrac{1}{k} = K \in (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \})$

$\Rightarrow (y_1, y_2, y_3)^T = K (x_1, x_2, x_3)^T$

$\therefore y \sim x$

(Since $(y_1, y_2, y_3)^T \in X$, $(x_1, x_2, x_3)^T \in X$, $K \in (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \})$, and $(y_1, y_2, y_3)^T = K (x_1, x_2, x_3)^T$, we can conclude that $((y_1, y_2, y_3)^T, (x_1, x_2, x_3)^T) \in R$ and $y \sim x$.)

2. (Proof that $(y \sim x) \Rightarrow (x \sim y)$.)

Same argument as above.

$Q.E.D.$

**Transitivity:**

Let $x^T, y^T, z^T \in X$.

$x^T = k_1 y^T$, where $k_1 \in (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \})$

$y^T = k_2 z^T$, where $k_2 \in (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \})$

(Since the hypothesis assumes that $x \sim y$ and $y \sim z$, we have that $(x^T, y^T) \in R$ and $(y^T, z^T) \in R$, which implies that $k_1, k_2 \in (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \})$.)

$\therefore x = k_1(k _2 z)$

$\Rightarrow x = (k_1 k_2) z$

$\Rightarrow x = Kz$, where $k_1 k_2 = K \in (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \})$

(Since $k_1, k_2 \in (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \})$, we have that $K \in (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \})$.)

$\therefore x \sim z$

(Since $x^T \in X$, $z^T \in X$, $K \in (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \})$, and $x = Kz$, we can conclude that $(x^T, z^T) \in R$ and $x \sim z$.)

$Q.E.D.$

Comment: Reflexivity is just wrong. What you want to show is that for every $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in X$, you have $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\sim (x_1,x_2,x_3)$, by producing an explicit $k$ (or showing such a $k$ exists). But you claim that the fact that $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is in $X$ somehow implies $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=k(x,y,z)$. You never say **who** this mysterious $(x,y,z)$ is, you never say who $k$ is. That’s wrong.

Comment: For symmetry, you should explicitly note that $K$ is a real number because $k\neq 0$, and you also need to note that $K\neq 0$. Similarly, for Transitivity, you need to show that $K$ is not zero.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for the review. I have attempted to fix the errors that you described. Is it correct now?

Comment: No; you still don’t say who $k$ is in the reflexivity; you need to **exhibit** a scalar that works, but you don’t exhibit one. You just introduce one without saying where it came from or what it is. And you still do not *explain* why your $K$s in the second and third part are nonzero, you just assert that this is the case. You need to *justify* the assertion, not just make it. (Also, the “therefore” in the second line of your Reflexivity proof does not make any sense; don’t think that putting in symbols substitutes for making sense)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks again. I have gone through every step and made changes and added justifications (especially for $K$). What do you think?

Comment: “Without loss of generality” is not the correct thing to say in your proof of symmetry. That is said when you have two or more possibilities to check, but it suffices to establish one of them. That is not what you have there. And you *still* don’t explain why your constants in the second and third part are nonzero, or why $K$ makes sense in part 2. All it takes is a simple observation, but it needs to be made explicitly.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin For symmetry, I stated that it is so by the definition of $R$, since we have assumed that $x \sim y$. For transitivity, I have again stated that it is by the definition of $R$, since we have assumed that $x \sim y$ and $y \sim z$. I don't understand how the explanations are insufficient?

Comment: That’s not the reason why $K$ is nonzero and sensible. The reason $K$ is nonzero and sensible is that $k$ is nonzero, so it has a reciprocal that is nonzero. The reason the $K$ is nonzero in transitivity is that $k_1$ and $k_2$ are nonzero, and therefore $K=k_1k_2$ is nonzero. You need to *say it*, explicitly, not just say “by definition”.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Hmm, ok, I see what you mean. I will make those changes now. Thanks again.